# Mongodb: db automatically drops after a while

Tags: mongodb

My code was working fine till yesterday- performing simple insert, update operations. Since yesterday, database automatically drops. On checking local.oplog.rs, i found the last entry as drop every time even though my code doesn't drop db anywhere.

```
    { 
    "ts" : Timestamp(1484893960, 1), 
    "t" : NumberLong(3), 
    "h" : NumberLong(-945311492786762202), 
    "v" : NumberInt(2), 
    "op" : "c", 
    "ns" : "randomdb.$cmd", 
    "o" : {
    "dropDatabase" : NumberInt(1)
    }
    }
```

The mongodb is deployed on a virtual machine (bitnami) on Microsoft Azure.

Interestingly, the db drops anytime- sometimes while in use, sometimes while idle.

Comment: Do you maybe have an integration test misconfigured that drops the production database instead of an embedded one?

Comment: Have you enabled authentication and properly secured your MongoDB deployment? Do you see any any new databases being created outside of those you expect? There have been a recent round of attacks dropping data on unsecured databases. See: [How to Avoid a Malicious Attack That Ransoms Your Data](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data) and [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).

Comment: @Shantanu Pandey - Did you found the solution for this ?

Comment: @Stennie - Did you found the solution for this ?

Comment: @US-1234 I assume this is an unsecured deployment where an attacker is remotely dropping databases. If so, the solution would be to implement the security measures outlined on the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) (enable access control & user authentication, configure firewall, etc).

Comment: Hi All! Apologies for delayed response. Stennie was right and thank you! Learnt a lesson to never keep an unsecured deployment online, even for test. Putting security measured fixed this.